# JavaScript on Contact Form Submit Button

Tags: javascript, dom-events

```
<p><script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
span data-mce-type="bookmark" id="mce_0_start" data-mce-style="overflow:hidden;line height:0px" style="overflow:hidden;line-height:0px"></span>// <![CDATA[
function validate(){ var x=document.forms["contactform"]["FirstName"].value; if (x==null || x == '') { alert("First name is mandatory"); return false; } var y=document.forms["contactform"]["LastName"].value; if (y==null || y == '') { alert("Last name is mandatory"); return false; } _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Contact Form', 'Submit']); window.open('/thank-you/'); }
// ]]&gt;</script></p>

<form action="https://docs.google.com/macros/exec?service=AKfycbygk9rnr-Iwp11I92KWsBXgfDHXLozZFost-IP" method="post" name="contactform" onsubmit="return validate()">
```

This is for the consultation form here: http://www.handytax.ca/free-consultation/

This code only results in both a conversion and thank you window open in IE6, IE8 and Firefox. In IE9, Chrome, Safari, and others neither the conversion nor the window open occur. In Chrome, the first and last name validation don't even occur. How do I fix this?

Comment: did you copy and paste that incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is that code inside your script tag

```
span data-mce-type="bookmark" id="mce_0_start" data-mce-style="overflow:hidden;line height:0px" style="overflow:hidden;line-height:0px"></span>// <![CDATA[
```

If you check with Chrome console (CTRL-SHIFT-J) you will see

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

Try to fix it/remove it and your Javascript code should run properly.

Answer (score 0):

I would take out the inline script and do your validation with something like the following

1. give your form an id - i.e. id="myForm"
2. setup your validation in the document.onReady()..this is shorthand for that

.

```
$(function(){
    $('#myForm').submit(function(){
    //do validation in here
    //if validation fails, then return false so the form is not submitted.
    });
});
```

Comment: This example uses jquery and your site has jquery on it.